# Kubernetes DNS no longer resolving names

Tags: kubernetes, dns, calico, kubespray

I have a cluster consisting of 6 servers, 3 masters and 3 workers.
Up to this morning everything worked fine, until I removed two workers from the cluster.

Now the internal DNS is not working anymore.
I cannot resolve an internal name.
Apparently google.com is resolved and I can ping it.

My cluster is running Kubernetes V1.18.2 (calico for networking), installed with kubespray.
I can access my services from outside, but when it's time for them to connect to each other, they fail (for example when the UI tries to connect to the database).

I provide below some of the output from the command listed here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/

**kubectl exec -ti busybox-6899b748d7-pbdk4 -- cat /etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 10.233.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local ovh.net
options ndots:5
```

**kubectl exec -ti busybox-6899b748d7-pbdk4 -- nslookup kubernetes.default**

```
Server:         10.233.0.10
Address:        10.233.0.10:53

** server can't find kubernetes.default: NXDOMAIN

*** Can't find kubernetes.default: No answer

command terminated with exit code 1
```

**kubectl exec -ti busybox-6899b748d7-pbdk4 -- nslookup google.com**

```
Server:         10.233.0.10
Address:        10.233.0.10:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.22.142

*** Can't find google.com: No answer
```

**kubectl exec -ti busybox-6899b748d7-pbdk4 -- ping google.com**

```
PING google.com (172.217.22.142): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.22.142: seq=0 ttl=52 time=4.409 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.22.142: seq=1 ttl=52 time=4.359 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 4.359/4.384/4.409 ms
```

**kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns**

```
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-74b594f4c6-5k6kq   1/1     Running   2          6d7h
coredns-74b594f4c6-9ct8x   1/1     Running   0          16m
```

when I get the logs for the DNS pods:
**for p in $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name); do kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $p; done**
they are full of:

```
E0522 11:56:22.613704       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.233.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
E0522 11:56:33.678487       1 reflector.go:307] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to watch *v1.Service: Get https://10.233.0.1:443/api/v1/services?allowWatchBookmarks=true&resourceVersion=1667490&timeout=8m12s&timeoutSeconds=492&watch=true: dial tcp 10.233.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
E0522 12:19:42.356157       1 reflector.go:307] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to watch *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.233.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?allowWatchBookmarks=true&resourceVersion=1667490&timeout=6m39s&timeoutSeconds=399&watch=true: dial tcp 10.233.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
E0522 12:19:42.356327       1 reflector.go:307] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to watch *v1.Service: Get https://10.233.0.1:443/api/v1/services?allowWatchBookmarks=true&resourceVersion=1667490&timeout=6m41s&timeoutSeconds=401&watch=true: dial tcp 10.233.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
```

The coredns service is up:
**kubectl get svc --namespace=kube-system**

```
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
coredns                     ClusterIP   10.233.0.3      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   7d4h
dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.233.52.242   <none>        8000/TCP                 7d4h
kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.233.63.42    <none>        443/TCP                  7d4h
voyager-operator            ClusterIP   10.233.31.206   <none>        443/TCP,56791/TCP        6d5h
```

The endpoints are exposed:
**kubectl get ep coredns --namespace=kube-system**

```
NAME      ENDPOINTS                                                    AGE
coredns   10.233.68.9:53,10.233.79.7:53,10.233.68.9:9153 + 3 more...   7d4h
```

What did I break? How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**
More information requested in the comments:
**kubectl get pods -n kube-system**

```
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-5d9cfb4bfd-8h7jd      1/1     Running   0          3d14h
calico-node-6w8g6                             1/1     Running   13         4d15h
calico-node-78thq                             1/1     Running   6          7d19h
calico-node-cr4jl                             1/1     Running   23         4d16h
calico-node-g5q99                             1/1     Running   1          3d15h
calico-node-pmss2                             1/1     Running   0          3d15h
calico-node-zw9fk                             1/1     Running   18         4d19h
coredns-74b594f4c6-5k6kq                      1/1     Running   2          6d22h
coredns-74b594f4c6-9ct8x                      1/1     Running   0          15h
dns-autoscaler-7594b8c675-j5jfv               1/1     Running   0          15h
kube-apiserver-kub1                           1/1     Running   42         7d20h
kube-apiserver-kub2                           1/1     Running   1          7d19h
kube-apiserver-kub3                           1/1     Running   33         7d19h
kube-controller-manager-kub1                  1/1     Running   37         7d20h
kube-controller-manager-kub2                  1/1     Running   4          3d15h
kube-controller-manager-kub3                  1/1     Running   55         7d19h
kube-proxy-4dlf8                              1/1     Running   4          4d15h
kube-proxy-4nlhf                              1/1     Running   2          4d15h
kube-proxy-82kkz                              1/1     Running   3          4d15h
kube-proxy-lvsfz                              1/1     Running   0          3d15h
kube-proxy-pmhnx                              1/1     Running   4          4d15h
kube-proxy-wpfnn                              1/1     Running   10         4d15h
kube-scheduler-kub1                           1/1     Running   34         7d20h
kube-scheduler-kub2                           1/1     Running   3          7d19h
kube-scheduler-kub3                           1/1     Running   51         7d19h
kubernetes-dashboard-7dbcd59666-79gxv         1/1     Running   0          3d14h
kubernetes-metrics-scraper-6858b8c44d-g9m9w   1/1     Running   1          5d22h
nginx-proxy-galaxy                            1/1     Running   2          4d15h
nginx-proxy-kub4                              1/1     Running   7          4d19h
nginx-proxy-kub5                              1/1     Running   6          4d16h
nodelocaldns-2dv59                            1/1     Running   0          3d15h
nodelocaldns-9skxm                            1/1     Running   5          4d16h
nodelocaldns-dwg4z                            1/1     Running   4          4d15h
nodelocaldns-nmwwz                            1/1     Running   12         7d19h
nodelocaldns-qkq8n                            1/1     Running   4          4d19h
nodelocaldns-v84jj                            1/1     Running   8          7d19h
voyager-operator-5677998d47-psskf             1/1     Running   10         4d15h
```

Comment: share output of kubectl get pods -n kube-system. Does it work if you delete the pod and recreate it? the /etc/resolve.conf file of the pods is not having the correct ip of the coredns service

Comment: how did you remove the nodes?

Comment: Did you check kubelet service logs? Kubelet suppose to write kubedns ClusterIP in `/etc/resolv.conf` file each pod it creates. But here it has configured a wrong IP.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu What is the correct IP? I added the pods in the kube-system namespace to the question. It Doesn't work if I delete and re-create the pods.

Comment: @paltaa ansible-playbook -i inventory/.../hosts.yaml -b -v remove-node.yml -e limit=kub6,kub7

Comment: @hariK What is the correct IP? If I check the kubelet logs now, there are no errors being shown. What should I look for?

Comment: 10.233.0.3 is the correct IP of coredns and should be in /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu OK,makes sense, since the service is running at that IP, but what triggered that change? How can I investigate and solve this?

Comment: coredns is trying to contact Kubernetes API Server at 10.233.0.1 and failing. Can you try restarting coredns pods. can you check if there is a service or pod at serving at IP 10.233.0.1

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu On the other hand, it doesn't make sense. Why is google.com resolved? If i manually edit the /etc/resolv.conf file in a pod, the lookup of kubernetes.default is still not working.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I just restarted both coreDNS pods, the situation persists. The same /etc/resolv.conf contents,cannot resolve an internal IP. But the coreDNS logs are empty this time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the scenario.

```
$ kubectl exec -it busybox -n dev -- nslookup kubernetes.default    
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10:53

** server can't find kubernetes.default: NXDOMAIN

*** Can't find kubernetes.default: No answer

command terminated with exit code 1
$ kubectl exec -it busybox -n dev -- nslookup google.com        
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.168.238

*** Can't find google.com: No answer

$ kubectl exec -it busybox -n dev -- ping google.com    
PING google.com (172.217.168.238): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.168.238: seq=0 ttl=52 time=18.425 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.168.238: seq=1 ttl=52 time=27.176 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.168.238: seq=2 ttl=52 time=18.603 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.168.238: seq=3 ttl=52 time=15.445 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.168.238: seq=4 ttl=52 time=16.492 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.168.238: seq=5 ttl=52 time=19.294 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 15.445/19.239/27.176 ms
```

But I followed the same steps using `dnsutils` image. Which has mentioned in Kubernetes [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/). It gives a positive response.

```
$ kubectl exec -ti dnsutils -n dev -- nslookup kubernetes.default   
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.0.1


$ kubectl exec -ti dnsutils -n dev -- nslookup google.com        
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.168.238
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:400e:80c::200e
```

As per my understanding, something wrong with the dnsutils in busybox container here. That's why we're getting this DNS resolve error.

Comment: I will mark this as the solution, since indeed the busybox container posed some problems even after I could access services across containers. But it was not the culprit, nor was the nameserver's IP configured in the pod's /etc/resolv.conf. I think it all sorted itself out after I deleted all the DNS related containers and the services in the cluster. I'm still not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution is super easy. I encountered this issue with K8S v1.26.0 on ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. Simply delete those 2 coredns pods then DNS would be resumed.

```
$ kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-787d4945fb-b8c57   1/1     Running   0          3h42m
coredns-787d4945fb-lvwdn   1/1     Running   0          3h42m
$
$ kubectl delete pod coredns-787d4945fb-b8c57 -n kube-system 
pod "coredns-787d4945fb-b8c57" deleted
$
$ kubectl delete pod  coredns-787d4945fb-lvwdn -n kube-system 
pod "coredns-787d4945fb-lvwdn" deleted
$
$ kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-787d4945fb-5nsmn   1/1     Running   0          28s
coredns-787d4945fb-66fb7   1/1     Running   0          11s
$
$ kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:         172.17.0.10
Address:        172.17.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 172.17.0.1

$ kubectl get svc
NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes              ClusterIP   172.17.0.1      <none>        443/TCP   3h45m
nginx-resolve-service   ClusterIP   172.17.26.238   <none>        80/TCP    117m
$
$ kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup nginx-resolve-service
Server:         172.17.0.10
Address:        172.17.0.10#53

Name:   nginx-resolve-service.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 172.17.26.238
```

But I have no idea why I always have such issue after creating a new cluster with
[vkk - vagrant-kubeadm-kubernetes](https://github.com/techiescamp/vagrant-kubeadm-kubernetes)